# How to make authentication to log in a website with Google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to make an authentication and then post an ad to a website with a Google Apps Script.
The plan is like this:

1. Make an authentication to log in by HTTP post method.
2. Get response and get cookies needed.
3. Send a new post request with needed content of an ad and cookies to make the website identify the script as a "logged in user".

I'm stuck on the 1st stage.
I made this script:

```
function sendHttpPost() {
   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "login[email]" : "mihsav76@gmail.com",
     "login[password]" : "testpas"              
   };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://olx.ua/myaccount/", options);
   var sessionDetails = response.getAllHeaders();       
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
 }
```

Credentials I got through Developer Console. Screenshot is attached.

[image: http post method by google script]

HTML code which I get from response is just a starting log in page. What is done wrong on this stage?

Comment: feel free to use those testing credentials

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the login parameters as options to UrlFetchApp, but you need to pass them as fields in the POST body.  This is done with the 'payload' option.

```
   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload":{"login[email]" : "mihsav76@gmail.com",
                "login[password]" : "testpas"
               }
   };
```

See the "advanced parameters" table and examples in the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the initial script, but the response through `response.getContentText()` function which is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11RBtw_dqZ2r-iuv2NcKuSr1xl8yqy45tDNKUn8LouPw/edit) is still the log in page. I don't see any evidence of successful authorization.

Comment: There are many possible reasons this might not still work, but the structure in my answer is the correct way to pass the POST payload.  The remote site may be checking other fields or headers in the request, or it may be that the field names need to be formatted differently.  Viewing the HTML source of the original (working) login page may yield some hints.

Comment: Well, and how to check which other fields or headers does this site need? If you would have a desire to delve into the issue a bit more, please feel free to use credentials above. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: From the looks of it, the login request is actually sent not to `http://olx.ua/myaccount/`, but to `https://ssl.olx.ua/account/?ref%5B0%5D%5Baction%5D=myaccount&ref%5B0%5D%5Bmethod%5D=index`. The query string decodes to 2 params: _ref[0][action]:myaccount_ and _ref[0][method]:index_. Try editing your code accordingly and see if it works - no guarantees, though, as the login script may have other behind-the-scenes stuff that you will have to work around (it does actually return a 301 Moved Permanently status code and redirects to olx.ua/myaccount - you may have to account for that in your code)