# Google Apps Script App - allow access for selected users without the need of user interaction

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, web-applications, ip, query-string

I am facing the following challenge:

**Am I able to authenticate the user for published Web App without the need for any interaction from the user eg. IP, URL parameter etc.?**

As I found out the IP authentification is not possible due to the fact you always get the Google Proxy IP due to the sandboxing.

I am thinking about using a URL parameter to do this. Do you think it is safe enough?

Also, I am aware of all the other options: using Google login, running the app under the user instead of me, using old school login/password and check against a database, publishing the app under the Gsuite domain and giving chosen users the access.

I am just looking for the simplest way, possibly without the need for the interaction.

Thank you for any ideas, resources.

Comment: You actually opted out for all the options I thought at first glance. Also URL parameter is not a really safe way to deliver authentication. Could you maybe share what is exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to run an Web App which will display some information from Google Sheets  on various store location cash desks running Windows, the easiest way to do this was to create Web App interface to display these information without the need of logging in, which on such a shared POS (point of sale) system might be challenging, therefore I am looking for other ways.

Comment: You can get the ip client side by get/post using `fetch` to say https://httpbin.org/get (or post)

Comment: Would having the IP solve your problem? This could be not safe, if for example someone know the list of whitelisted IP and change the value to "fool" your system.     
Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391239/how-to-make-authentication-to-log-in-a-website-with-google-scripts) maybe helps you. You also could share an id and password to every store.